# Get rid of name and hostname in a terminal prompt

Tags: customization, bashrc, ps1, powerline-plugin

I use [powerline-shell](https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell) and my prompt looks like:

[image].

How can I get rid of my name and hostname  in the prompt?

I tried to search in `.bashrc` file for `PS1` variables:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u:\w\$ '
fi
```

Which I have to edit to the goal?

Comment: Since you are using powerline-shell, which claims to provide "A beautiful and useful prompt for your shell [that is] easy to customize and extend", then I would venture that the answer to your question is in the powerline-shell documentation. It almost certainly won't help to change your bash prompt, as the whole point of prompt beautifiers is that they _replace_ the bash prompt.

Comment: Well the sequence for **h**ostname would be `\h` - so for example the default Ubuntu `~/.bashrc` (copied from `/etc/skel/.bashrc`) includes `\u@\h` in its `PS1` string - yours does not appear to do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this in your powerline config file which is normally located under `~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json`.

If you haven't one yet you can create one using the following commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/powerline-shell
powerline-shell --generate-config > ~/.config/powerline-shell/config.json
```

Then simply remove the segments you dont want like `username` or `hostname`.
For more information see [the docs](https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell#customization)